# shell file redirection

Tags: c, shell

I'm writing a shell script for class in C and I got my program to execute all commands except for file redirection. Can someone help figure out how I need to go about file redirection, I know I need to do it when fork returns 0, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

CODE: 
Here is an updated version of my code. Creates the file fine but then i'm not sure what to do after. I close the correct file descriptors I think then duplicate my file descriptor to the lowest open descriptor. after dup besides closing the correct file descriptor can you help me what to do?

args[] is the array that i store the input (i.e. ls -l, ls -l > out)

```
if ((cpid = fork()) == 0)
{
  for ( i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    if ( *args[i] == '<' )
    {
      if ((fd = open(args[i+1], O_RDONLY)) == -1)
      {
        perror("open");
        exit(2);
      }
      else
      {
        close(0);
        dup(fd);
        close(fd);
      }
    }
    if ( *args[i] == '>' )
    {
      if ((fd = open(args[i+1], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644)) == -1)
      {
        perror("open");
        exit(2);
      }
      else
      {
        close(1);
        dup(fd);
        close(fd);
      }
    }
  }

  execve(path,args,environ);
  perror("execve");
  exit(2);
}
```

Comment: habe you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647663/help-with-simple-linux-shell-implementation ?

Comment: I did look but didnt find that, thanks for the link I will check it out. looks promising!

Comment: I looked up that post and updated my code is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `dup` function [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2)

Comment: How about posting an example?